# from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty Error with Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy, kivy-language

Hey i am new to kivy and i make a really basic Kivy program following step by step Tech with tim video tutorial about Kivy but for some reason in my computer the is an error with the from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty and i found that one solution is to change the from "kivy.properties import ObjectProperty" to "import kivy.properties as kyprops" and then type kyprops anytime i need to declare ObjectProperty but i am still getting this 2 errors " in  class MyGrid(Widget): " and " in MyGrid name = kyprops(None)  TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" Any ideas ? here is the code

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import kivy.properties as kyprops

class MyGrid(Widget):
    name = kyprops.ObjectProperty(None)
    email = kyprops.ObjectProperty(None)

    def btn(self):
        print("Name:", self.name.text, "email:", self.email.text)
        self.name.text = ""
        self.email.text = ""

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

and the Kv code is this

```
#:kivy !ex
<MyGrid>:

    name: name
    email: email

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width - 200, root.height -200
        pos: 100, 100

        GridLayout:
            cols:2

            Label:
                text: "Name: "

            TextInput:
                id: name
                multiline:False

            Label:
                text: "Email: "

            TextInput:
                id: email
                multiline:False

        Button:
            text:"Submit"
            on_press: root.btn()
```

Comment: You probably want to use `kyprops.ObjectProperty(None)`.

Comment: nope now i actually have more errors that before (http://prntscr.com/zuskyt)

Answer (score 0):

Remove from your `kv`, the line:

```
#:kivy !ex
```

That is not a legal kivy version specification.

Comment: yeah i know it was for vc code but is not working on vs code either so yeah dont really pay attention to that

Comment: But kivy will pay attention to it. That is causing your error.